# Prestashop fatal error on On Sale Module

Tags: module, prestashop

I downloaded module **ROJA45: ON SALE PRODUCTS**, it's free and easy to find on google.

After installation i have problem with seeing all on sale on one page.

First was showing error with controller so i changed name of it from: `roja45onsaleproducts.php` to: `Roja45OnSaleProducts.php` and then another error apeared.

In debug now I see error:

> Fatal error: Call to private method Roja45OnSaleProducts::getProductsToDisplay() from context 'Roja45OnSaleProductsRoja45OnSaleProductsModuleFrontController' in /home/psdes/domains/dev/moto-center/modules/roja45onsaleproducts/controllers/front/Roja45OnSaleProducts.php on line 68

And line 68 in this error is:

```
$products = Roja45OnSaleProducts::$cache_onsale_products;
if ($products === null) {
    $products = Roja45OnSaleProducts::getOnSaleProducts((int) $this->context->language->id, 0, (int) Configuration::get('PS_ROJA45_ONSALE_PRODUCTS_NBR'));
}
```

Line 68 is just:

```
$products = Roja45OnSaleProducts::getOnSaleProducts((int) $this->context->language->id, 0, (int) Configuration::get('PS_ROJA45_ONSALE_PRODUCTS_NBR'));
```

Can someone take a look what could be wrong?

I can't get any information about that from module developer.

Answer (score 0):

In module file `roja45onsaleproducts.php` change `private function getOnSaleProducts(...)` to `public function getOnSaleProducts(...)`.